# Performance License for 4321

Tags: cisco, cisco-isr

I'am trying to install an FL-4320-PERF-K9 (Performance) License on an ISR4321 to increase throughput from 85 mbit to 100 mbit but it tells me that there is a better license installed already.. Does anyone know what that is and how i can see that? Log messages clearly describes that it is using the maximum bandwith of 85 mbit for this license platform...

```
%CERM_DP-4-DP_TX_BW_LIMIT: Maximum Tx Bandwidth limit of 85000 Kbps reached for Crypto functionality with securityk9 technology package license.

Router#license install flash:<hidden.lic>
Installing licenses from "flash:<hidden.lic>" 
Installing...Feature:throughput...Failed:
% Error: Better license exists
```

Here is an output of show license:

[image]

Comment: may you provide us with the show version

Comment: Do you need the HSEC export unlock license?  You're not hitting the standard throughput license (50 or 100 mbps), just the crypto cap.  `FL-4320-HSEC-K9(=) U.S. Export Compliance Security PAK (E-Delivery/Paper) for Cisco 4321 (System & Spare)`

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

If throughput (performance) license is enabled as it is shown on the attached picture, your throughput is 100mbps. Using a 4321 you have 2 options. 50mbps without performance license, and 100mbps with it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the security licenses to activate the advanced security features offered on the Cisco 4000 Series ISR platform. The HSEC license is required for a feature to have full crypto functionality. Without the HSEC license, only 225 secure tunnels and 85 Mbps of crypto bandwidth would be available.

[enter link description here](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/products/collateral/routers/4000-series-integrated-services-routers-isr/guide-c07-732797.html)

The license quoted above however, is a FL-4320-PERF-K9, which will increase routing throughput from 50Mbps to 100Mbps on the Ethernet interfaces. You MUST activate it once installed:

1 – Install license:

```
06600r2#license install flash:FDO210102MX_20170401103432129.lic 
Installing licenses from "flash:FDO210102MX_20170401103432129.lic" 
Installing...Feature:throughput...Successful:Supported
1/1 licenses were successfully installed
```

2 – Apply/**configure** the new throughput level:

```
06600r2#conf t
Enter configuration commands, one per line.  End with CNTL/Z.

06600r2(config)#platform hardware throughput level 100000 
% The config will take effect on next reboot

06600r2#show platform hardware throughput level 
The current throughput level is 50000 kb/s
```

Following reboot:

3 – Confirm throughput:

```
06600r1#show platform hardware throughput level 
The current throughput level is 100000 kb/s
```

Answer (score -1):

You may need to enter the command "platform hardware throughput level xxxxxx" in order to enable the license.